# VB.Net Reverse Byte in Hex value

Tags: vb.net

```
    Private Sub LRbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles LRbtn.Click
    OpenFileDialog1.Title = "Please Select a File"
    OpenFileDialog1.ShowDialog()
    Dim filename As String = OpenFileDialog1.FileName
    Dim fs As FileStream = New FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open)
    Dim br As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(fs)
    br.BaseStream.Seek(verOffset, SeekOrigin.Begin)
    a = br.ReadInt32()
    verLabel.Text = hex2ascii(Hex(a))
    br.Close()
    fs.Close()

End Sub
```

I'm opening and Binary-reading a file, then i read 4 byte at the given address.

So for example the variable `a` might be `1163022402` that converted to Hex is `45,52,50,42`

After converting `a` to Hex i need to reverse the byte to obtain `42,50,52,45`

I'm new to VB and i'm learning it, how can i do? Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

Use `br.ReadBytes` if you need 32 bit just read 4 bytes then you can order them anyway you want

Comment: Ok but since i'm learning, how can i read 4 bytes using this function? Can you give me a example please? Thank you very much.

Comment: `byte[] dataArray = binReader.ReadBytes(4);`